# Can't find a proper audio output on Raspberry Pi 4B, whith an external sound card

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pyaudio

I am having issues with playing sound trhough headphones connected to a jack port, on an raspberry Pi expansion board. I'm using the "ReSpeaker 2-Mics Pi HAT", dual-microphone expansion board. I've installed the voice card source code.

My main point is to have a python script play a sound file with the use of pyaudio. I wanted to specify the `output_device_index` for pyaudio stream. To get the index I tried this code:

```
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')

for i in range(0, numdevices):
    if (p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('maxInputChannels')) > 0:
        print("Input Device id ", i, " - ", p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))
    else:
        print("Output Device id ", i, " - ", p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(0, i).get('name'))
```

but it gives me a bunch of ALSA warnings and only those devices:

```
Output Device id  0  -  sysdefault
Output Device id  1  -  lavrate
Output Device id  2  -  samplerate
Output Device id  3  -  speexrate
Input Device id  4  -  pulse
Output Device id  5  -  upmix
Output Device id  6  -  vdownmix
Output Device id  7  -  playback
Input Device id  8  -  capture
Output Device id  9  -  dmixed
Input Device id  10  -  array
Output Device id  11  -  dmix
Input Device id  12  -  default
```

When I run `aplay -l` and `arecord -l` the [seeed-2mic-voicecard] is listed correctly

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 7/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: vc4hdmi0 [vc4-hdmi-0], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: vc4hdmi1 [vc4-hdmi-1], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: seeed2micvoicec [seeed-2mic-voicecard], device 0: bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0 [bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 3: seeed2micvoicec [seeed-2mic-voicecard], device 0: bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0 [bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

After running a test audio file:

```
arecord -D "plughw:3,0" -f S16_LE -r 16000 -d 5 -t wav test.wav
aplay -D "plughw:3,0" test.wav
```

the sound records and plays without issues.

I just don't know how to access the audio devices without the use of `aplay`. PulseAudio Volume control and Audacity don't pick up my output device.